# Directional derivative of a multivariable function

Tags: analysis

How can I find a directional derivative of a function
$$
f(x,y,z) = \sqrt[3]{x^3 +y^3 + z^3}
$$
in every direction in a point $[0,0,0]$? Does this function have a total differencial in that point?

Comment: Hint: $df=(x^2dx+y^2dy+z^2dz)(x^3+y^3+z^3)^{-2/3}$. Try a few directions.